# character pointer value is blank, why the code does not print 5?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>               

using namespace std;             

int main() {
   char* x=0;     //  initialize pointer character called x equals zero 
   cout<<x;       //  print the value of pointer in memory      
   cout<<5;       //  print 5 on screen  (not executed)  
}
```

line 9 does not executed by the compiler

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: no there is no error messages just blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ostream`'s `operator<<` has [an overload for `char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), this dereferences the pointer you pass to it.

This means you try to dereference a pointer pointing to `0` resulting in undefined behavior. In this case, your next print is not shown.

If you want to show the address you should cast to `void*` explicitly:

```
cout<< static_cast<const void*>(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a char pointer variable x = 0 which is null and trying to dereference a null pointer which resulted in a undefined behaviour.
Pointer variables should store only address of another variable